# Bash Last Carriage character, newline character stripping

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="p.txt"
while read line; do
    export http_proxy="http://$line"
    wget http://www.example.com
done < $FILE
```

the problem is, it gives the following error:

```
http://80.251.247.14:3128
: Bad port number.y URL http://80.251.247.14:3128
```

I think it is because of last character, either it is newline \n or \r, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tr -d '\n'`:

```
while read line; do
    export http_proxy=$(echo "http://$line" | tr -d '\n')
    wget http://www.example.com
done < $FILE
```

Comment: You may want to try `\r` (i.e. CR) instead of `\n` (or in addition).